# If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n3^n$ is convergent, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(-2)^n$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

My class was given a set of practice problems and I can't figure this one out.

> If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n3^n$ is convergent, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(-2)^n$ is convergent.

My intuition wants to say this is true, but I can't figure out why. I can't apply the ratio test between the two because $a_n$ could be alternating, and limit comparison test between the first sum and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n2^n$ doesn't work because the limit comparison test doesn't prove absolute convergence. I don't see any way to apply the alternating series theorem.

Essentially, this problem seems trivial if I know $a_n$ is either always positive or always negative, but any sort of alternation and it breaks down.

Comment: note that a series is convergent if it is absolutely convergent.

Comment: @AbishankaSaha The $a_n$'s are not promised to be non-negative.

Comment: This is a special case of an important fact about [*power series*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series): If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ converges for $x = x_0$ then it converges absolutely for all $x$ with $|x| < |x_0|$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}3^na_n$ converges then $\lim_{n\to\infty}3^na_n=0$, and so there is some $N$ such that
$$ |a_n|\leq 3^{-n}$$
for $n\geq N$. This then implies that
$$ |(-2)^na_n|\leq \Big(\frac{2}{3}\Big)^n$$
for $n\geq N$, and it follows that $\sum_n(-2)^na_n$ converges absolutely by comparison with a geometric series.

Comment: Wow, this makes a ton of sense. Thanks for this, I never thought to use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

The power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n*x^n$ has radius of convergence $ \ge 3$. Hence this power series converges for $x=-2$.